# How To Convert .htaccess To web.config without IIS

Tags: .htaccess, web-config

I have no IIS installed, and I need to convert my htaccess file to web.config

How to make .. 
Best Regards !

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ index.php?rqt=page/index/url/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rqt=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could not change the *.htaccess* file. Because it is present in Apache base Web-hosting server. If you are using the ASP.NET or ASP.Net MVC. Then you could not host it on the Apache Server. You could be a move to the IIS server hosting.

But, you still make the adventure to do this then move on to the ASP.Net Core 2.0 or latest version. In this, you may have some sort of changes in your Controller. For .Net Core Application, you will have the *appsetting.json* file. Which you can run Nigix, Apache, IIS, and Kestrel, etc.

After all, I prefer you to use the IIS Server or having the hosting server which uses the IIS environment.